# Leaking ice maker/dispenser, overfilling ice tray

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, ice-maker

**Info**:

GE® ENERGY STAR® 25.6 CU. FT. FRENCH-DOOR REFRIGERATOR

**Model**:

GFE26JSMKFSS

**Issue**:

Water coming out of the dispenser seemingly at random times, but I’ve correlated that dispensing with the time when the ice maker is filling the cube tray.

When water is manually dispensed from the fridge door, within the door ice maker, the water is also filling the ice tray, causing it to overflow.

My assumption is that a water valve which is meant to open and close is stuck open, so when the ice maker wants to fill its tray, it also dispenses out of the door dispenser and when water is manually dispensed from the door, the ice tray also fills.

Is this a mechanical issue or an electrical issue? Can I flush the water line to clean it so it closes? What can I do before calling a technician?

Comment: it could be the ice tray itself ... does the ice maker mechanism twist the tray to empty the ice cubes?

Comment: Usually it is just icing formation. Use hair dryer and taw it. If you do it under 5 minutes the rest of the fridge will be fine

Comment: I think in my refrigerator there are 2 independent water solenoids.  One for the ice and another for the water dispenser.  It is confusing to think how a refrigerator could be built to use only 1 water solenoid for both.

Comment: You can most certainly try to flush the line to see if that resolves the issue. Probably going to be difficult for anyone on this side of the internet to know for sure. If that doesn't fix it, it is either a mechanical or electrical issue. You'll have to do troubleshooting to figure that out.

Comment: @zakpucci, have you fixed your refrigerator? I am more and more convinced that my similar problem is because the fill timing is too long. On my refrigerator I believe this is under software control. So why it is happening now after over 10 years of service is a bit of a mystery.  All I can think of ... the city water pressure is a bit higher now. So... check if your GE has a measured water feature. If it does... check if there is a option to calibrate the measured water.  Calibrate it.  Then check if that fixes your ice tray water leaking problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.genuinereplacementparts.com/ge-gfe26jsmkfss-water-inlet-valve-genuine-oem) may or may not be the correct water valve for your refrigerator. Regardless, if it is a close match, it does appear to consist of 2 solenoids (two blue cylinder objects).  Indicating the possibility of independent control of the ice maker and dispenser water supply.

> Is this a mechanical issue or an electrical issue?

That is really hard to tell with out testing the electrical signals during normal operation.  Do you have the equipment to do this?  And can you do it safely?

In the end, the behavior you describe does not sound correct.  And the water valve may be the cause.

Comment: I had a similar issue on my fridge and it was the water inlet valve. In my case the valve would not shut at all, so as soon as I turned on the water supply line, the ice maker would fill, overflow, and the water would run out the door (as that is where gravity fed it)